# MongoDB AtlasProject encryption at rest crd - needed roles

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-iam, atlas

I want to enable encryption at rest via AtlasProject custom resource but I do not know how to specify AWS KMS and AWS IAM roles to make that happen. Atlas has different AWS Account ID than I have.
Does anyone know how to do that? How JSON files for roles and kms should look like?
(Link to AtlasProject cr doc: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/atlas-operator/atlasproject-custom-resource/#std-label-atlasproject-custom-resource)

I tried to do it with Atlas UI and it worked but it has to be done by AtlasProject cr. In the roles presented by Atlas UI there is unique external ID which is not present when creating it the other way.